# How to add and use a C++ dll in a UWP project

Tags: dll, uwp

I have created a UWP project in Visual Studio 2017. And I need to access some methods of a C++ dll from my UWP project. For that I have added the C++ dll in the \bin folder of the UWP project. And while debugging, it's showing some errors like

"Unable to load DLL 'testDll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

So I have copied the C++ dll into the \AppX folder. So the error is not showing but it's not working with the C++ dll.
Is there any steps to use a C++ dll in UWP project?

I have seen a step in google which is add the path of the library in the Additional Dependencies property of the UWP project (in Configuration Properties > Linker ) but I can't find the Linker option in configuration properties.

Could you please anyone help me with this.

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-160#BK_Win32DLL) before

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, but doesn't work

Comment: Could you mind share a repro sample for us with github or onedrive?